# Find the column index by its name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have three columns: `syscode`, `loc_cod`, `loc_name` but wanted to know if `loc_name` was 3rd in order. How could I retrieve that with an SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `information_schema` :

```
select col.table_name, col.column_name, 
       (case when col.ordinal_position = 3 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Position_flag
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as col
where col.table_name = <whatever> and col.column_name = 'loc_name';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have [sp_column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) in t-sql. One of items returned in the results set is ORDINAL_POSITION - *"Ordinal position of the column in the object. The first column in the object is 1. This column always returns a value."*

Usage:

```
exec sp_columns MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the column ordinal, name, and type from a `Query` or even a `Stored Procedure`

```
Select column_ordinal
      ,name
      ,system_type_name 
  From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select * from OD',null,null )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the `information_schema.columns` as shown below.

```
Select 
     * 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'TableA'
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f537705b729edde392b3651c4317c7e) demo.

You can also try the below one.

```
Select 
     Column_Name
     , ORDINAL_POSITION
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'TableA'
```

You can pass the column name in the filter as as shown below.

```
Select 
     * 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'TableA' and COLUMN_NAME = 'Code2'
```

Answer (score 1):

- The solutions with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` have a pyhsical table or view as target.
- The solutions with `...describe_first_result_set` need to pass the `SELECT` as a string, this might be a draw back (dynamic execution).

So there's one solution using the generic abilities of XQuery:

We use `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ...` to get a XML-result of one row. For demonstration I'm using `sys.objects` here:

```
DECLARE @YourSelect XML=
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM sys.objects o
    FOR XML PATH('')
);
```

--This is the query:

```
WITH tally(Nr) AS(SELECT TOP(@YourSelect.value('count(/*)','int')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT Nr
      ,@YourSelect.value('local-name((*[sql:column("Nr")])[1])','nvarchar(max)')
FROM tally;
```

The idea in short:

- We use a *tally-on-the-fly* with a computed `TOP()` clause in order to get a running list of numbers. The computed TOP will reduce this list to the actual count of columns.
- We use XQuery's `local-name()` and a wild-card-XPath with `*` to get each element by its position.

The result is a numbered list of column names.

```
Nr  column_name
1   name
2   object_id
3   schema_id
4   parent_object_id
5   type
6   type_desc
7   create_date
8   modify_date
9   is_ms_shipped
10  is_published
11  is_schema_published
```

Hint:

- You can add a `WHERE` clause to filter for a given column name
- This can be fully inlined, if needed...

Comment: Valid point regarding the dynamic SQL string, but I do like  the stored procedure aspect  either way +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I plusoned your answer too (for the same reasons :-) )

Comment: "plusoned" not a word, but is should be